# SSRS 2012 Report variables scope

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have a report that uses data from several datasets. I chose to do it this way because the alternative would be to join about 12 tables.

From what I can gather, I have to use the dataset name to define the scope of the variable when using it in expressions. I have tried to do this, but I still get an error.

The expression I'm using is:

```
=(Fields!PropertyDescription.Value, "Application")
```

And the error I get is:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox11’ refers directly to the field ‘PropertyDescription’ without specifying a dataset aggregate. When the report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope.

Even if I use an expression such as

```
=First(Fields!PropertyDescription.Value, "Application")
```

I get the same error.

Can someone perhaps help me with this error or suggest another way of combining the data?

Comment: Do you have the option of creating a stored procedure that can produce a single dataset?

Comment: I'm not sure I haven't worked with stored procedures before. As long as it can run when the report needs to run, I guess it should be fine. The RDL will be converted to RDLC by a developer, don't know if that is a consideration.

Comment: The error says it all.  Your Application dataset is not, I am assuming, the main dataset.  The report will allow you to use it if it is part of an aggregate function - like SUM.  FIRST isn't an aggregate.  If you have the option of creating a stored proc, that would be your best option.  It get's the code out of the report, providing for better maintenance and a stored proc is much more powerful and flexible.   As long as it produces a single dataset, your report should be happy.

Comment: I'm gathering that one can't have multiple datasets at the same 'level' in SSRS. I will investigate the stored procedure option.

Comment: After some more research I realised that what I wanted was data regions. I'm now using different lists and tablixes to bind to different datasets.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I realised that what I wanted was data regions. I'm now using different lists and tablixes to bind to the different datasets.